Rod cutting problem: alternate recurrence in interview
The rod cutting problem is described in section 15.1 of the book "Introduction to algorithms" by Carmen et.al. We are given an array, p where p[j] represents the money we'll get for a rod of length j. Given a rod of length n, what is the most money that can be made by cutting it optimally and selling the pieces?
The recurrence covered in the book which the solution is based on describes the dynamic programming array, x where x[j] represents the most money that can be made by cutting and selling a rod of length j. By taking the max across various choices of the first cut we get the recurrence:
x[n] = max(p[i] +x[n-i]); 0 <= i <= n
And then the solution is based on this.
Now, I asked this in an interview and the person came up with the following recurrence:
x[n] = max(x[i] +x[n-i]); 1 <= i <= n-1
I don't see a good reason why this second recurrence won't work. We can think of it as conditioning on there being a cut at position i. It does seem like the program we create will be less efficient than one based on the original recurrence.
Is there a way to quantify how much worse a program based on the second recurrence will be and why it might be a bad idea to use it?

The first recurrence is incorrect because it's circular (set i=0 and see). The proposed recursion is incorrect because it doesn't account for a possibility of not cutting the rod at all, but the idea is fixable by taking x[n] = max(p[n],max(x[i] +x[n-i])). Also, by symmetry you only need to run i up to n/2.

Is p[0] defined? I hope it is not non-zero if it is...

As commented, both recurrence relations have issues:

x[n] = max(p[i] + x[n-i]); 0 <= i <= n
Here i can be 0, which would define x[n] in terms of itself (infinite recursion). It is not specified whether p[0] is provided. If it is provided, it should certainly be 0 to make sense.
Also, i can be n, which would query x[0], but then we need to define x[0] as a separate base case as we already excluded that i could be 0 with the previous point. Of course, x[0] should then be defined as 0.
x[0] = 0
x[n] = max(p[i] + x[n-i]); n > 0, 0 < i <= n
As x[n] = p[n] is considered as a candidate now, and this is also the base case (n == 0), we could embed that option into the max operation and only consider i < n for the other candidates:
x[n] = max(p[n], p[i] + x[n-i] for 0 < i < n)


x[n] = max(x[i] + x[n-i]); 1 <= i <= n-1
This one prevents the boundary problems for i, but does not consider the case where the rod of size n should not be cut, in which case x[n] = p[n].
As the terms of the sum are exchangeable, we can limit i to n/2, but then still need to consider x[n] = p[n].
x[n] = max(p[n], x[i] + x[n-i] for 0 < i <= n / 2)


So we end up with these two alternatives:

x[n] = max(p[n], p[i] + x[n-i] for 0 < i < n)
x[n] = max(p[n], x[i] + x[n-i] for 0 < i <= n / 2)

The second recurrence has to check fewer candidates than the first one, although this difference is not significant in terms of time complexity. Both have a O(²) time complexity (with dynamic programming tabulation).
Here is a stress test of implementations for both, in JavaScript:


function solve1(p, size) {
    const x = Array(size + 1);
    for (let n = 0; n <= size; n++) {
        x[n] = p[n];
        for (let i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            x[n] = Math.max(x[n], p[i] + x[n - i]); 
        }
    }
    return x[size];
}

function solve2(p, size) {
    const x = Array(size + 1);
    for (let n = 0; n <= size; n++) {
        x[n] = p[n];
        for (let i = n >> 1; i > 0; i--) {
            x[n] = Math.max(x[n], x[i] + x[n - i]); 
        }
    }
    return x[size];
}

// Bulk test with random sampling of p for a rod of size 100.
let size = 100;
let start;
let time1 = 0, time2 = 0; // Accumulated time spent on execution
for (let test = 1; test <= 10000; test++) {
    // Define p with random values, sorted
    let p = Array.from({length: size + 1}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
                 .sort((a,b) => a-b);
    p[0] = 0; // This is required (in case an algorithm would read it)

    // Execute and measure the first solution:
    start = performance.now();
    let a = solve1(p, size);
    time1 += performance.now() - start;

    // Execute and measure the second solution:    
    start = performance.now();
    let b = solve2(p, size);
    time2 += performance.now() - start;
    
    // Assert that both return the same result
    console.assert(a === b, "solve1 and solve2 output different results!");
}
console.log("Milliseconds on solve1:", Math.ceil(time1));
console.log("Milliseconds on solve2:", Math.ceil(time2));



